# Suppose that the function f(x)

Tags: analysis, functions

Suppose that a function $f(x)$ defined on $[0,1]$ satisfies
$f(1/n)\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. Can we say that  $f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to 0^+$ if $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ ? and again

is it true $f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to 0^+$ if  $f$ is differentiable on $(0,1)$ ?

I can see this true for some problems when using Maple to plot them, but I need to prove/disprove that. If anyone can prove this for me.

Many thanks.

Comment: Continuity is sufficient - you don't need differentiability.

Comment: Continuity and limits are unique do it for you.

Comment: The first condition is sufficient, and the second condition is insufficient by looking at the counterexample $$ f(x) = \begin{cases} \sin(\pi/x) & 0 < x \leq 1 \\ 0 & x = 0 \end{cases}, $$ which is differentiable on $(0, 1)$ and satisfies $f(1/n) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ but nevertheless $f(x)$ does not converge as $x \to 0^+$.

Comment: @sos440: you are giving a very good answer, so I would suggest you write it as an answer and not as a comment.

Comment: well, but f(1/n)doesn't approach 0 as n goes to infinity. so the limit of f(1/n) is sin(nPi) which is -1,1 as n goes to infinity.

Answer (score 4):

As is noted in the comments, continuity is enough.  It allows us to pass the limit inside of the function:

$$0=\lim_{n\to\infty}f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=f\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\right)=f(0)$$

It follows that $f(0)=0$, and since $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, we know that $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=f(0)=0$.

Notice that the domain include $0$ is a necessary condition.  Consider the function $f(x)=\sin(\frac{\pi}{x})$, which is continuous and differentiable on $(0,1)$, satisfies $f(\frac{1}{n})=0$ for all $n$, but has no continuous extension to $[0,1]$.